# MyBatis data querying issues

Tags: sql, h2, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Here's a sample code:

```
@Results(
        id = "displayData", value = {
        @Result(property = "Caller", column = "c.CALLER"),
        @Result(property = "Event", column = "t.RECORD_TEXT"),
        @Result(property = "Receiver", column = "c.RECEIVER"),
        @Result(property = "Timestamp", column = "e.RECORD_DATE")
}
)
@Select("SELECT c.CALLER, c.RECEIVER, e.RECORD_DATE, t.RECORD_TEXT FROM T_CALL c " +
        "INNER JOIN T_EVENT e ON e.CALL_ID=c.RECORD_ID INNER JOIN T_EVENT_TYPE t " +
        "ON e.RECORD_EVENT_ID=t.RECORD_ID WHERE c.CALLER LIKE '%${searchTerm}%' OR " +
        "t.RECORD_TEXT LIKE '%${searchTerm}%' OR c.RECEIVER LIKE '%${searchTerm}%' " +
        "ORDER BY ${ordering} LIMIT ${limit} OFFSET ${offset}")
List<DisplayData> findAndSortDataToDisplay(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm, @Param("ordering") String ordering,
                                           @Param("limit") int limit, @Param("offset") int offset);
```

The problem with is that "Event" and "Timestamp" are set to NULL at runtime (other two are set properly)!
Can anyone help with some advice on how to fix this?

(The whole code is available here: https://github.com/arthurmarkus2013/SampleWebsite)

EDIT:

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems like this code does work:

```
@Select("SELECT c.CALLER, e.EVENTS_GROUP_ID FROM T_CALL c INNER JOIN T_EVENT e " + 
"ON e.CALL_ID=c.RECORD_ID WHERE c.CALLER = ${callerId}") 
int fetchEventsGroupId(@Param("callerId") int callerId);
```

The difference is, that this definition contains only one JOIN clause, whereas the first one contains two of them. In other words, I'm pretty much sure, that the issue is caused by those JOINs!
But the problem is, that I am provided with an absolute requirement, that both definitions work as intended!

Comment: I personally think, that JOINing operation doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

To help you, I need more details about DisplayData type.
If Event and Timestamp has a one-to-many/one-to-one relation with T_CALL you need read about association and collection.
refer to [Mybatis Docs](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html)

using annotations, refer to @Many @one [Mybatis annotations](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html)

I hope this can help you, good luck !

Comment: It's SQL only! Display data is just for simplifying use of returned result(s)!